# Playing with HTML's ordered list number bullets

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone think of a way to use the numbers in an `ol`/`li` list to label images?

```
<ol>
  <li><img /></li>
  <li><img /></li>
  <li><img /></li>
</ol>
```

With some CSS applied should output the following:

```
------ ------ ------
|    | |    | |    |
|    | |    | |    |
|   1| |   2| |   3|
------ ------ ------
```

Where each square is a small profile picture.

I know I can insert a new element in the `li` with a numeral in it and manipulate that as needed, but I'd like to do it with the inbuilt `ol` numbering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy enough:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: listCount;
}
li {
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid #f90;
    counter-increment: listCount;
    position: relative;
}
li:after {
    content: counter(listCount,decimal-leading-zero);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HSZrQ/1/).

This does, of course, require the user to have a browser with the capacity for using css-generated-content, which pretty rules out IE.

References:

- [CSS-generated counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#counters).

Answer (score 5):

Seems a little hacky IMHO but this works (in firefox atleast):

http://jsfiddle.net/ztfzt/14/

```
<ol>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" /></li>
</ol>

ol {}
ol li {
    float: left;
    list-style-position: inside;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    line-height: 170px;
    text-indent: 85px;
    color: #fff;
}
ol li img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I would just go with the additional element solution if I were you.

EDIT: tested in chrome, IE9 and 8. Seems to work consistently in both. Issues in IE7 however but can probably be fixed with a little extra browser specific css.

Comment: I think you'd want to put float:left on the "ol li" entry as the picture he submitted looks like the entries are one after another horizontally rather than vertically.

Comment: I didn't know about list-style-position.  Awesome answer